# input directives cents to dollars

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which allows me to start in the 1/100th column of a dollar amount. For instance, say the dollar amount I want to display in my form is 23.76 I would start typing 2, 3, 7, 6 and as I type, the displayed amount would be $0.02, $0.23, $2.37, $23.76, yet my module would be in cents so `2376`

I've put together a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqKRPW) but am running into an issue with leading zeros.  For instance, type in an amount, then delete it out to 0 and you'll see what I mean in the "Raw value" field, there will be trailing zeroes.

What can I do to ensure that if I type in an amount the raw value remains in cents with no leading zeros?

Comment: are you referring to $scope.currencyVal; in you html?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the "[number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)" filter of angular for this purpose. Add it to your html as: `{{moneyVal | number}}` here fraction size will be 0.

```
<div class="body" ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="info">Raw Value: {{moneyVal | number}}</div>


    <input class="input-phone" type='text' money-input ng-model="moneyVal" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Checkout the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/nithin_krishnan/pen/wGzmqr).

**Note:** This is an html level / presentation level solution.
Hope this helps... :)

Comment: That's not what I need.  I need the actual model value to have no leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I kept cracking and came up with this.  It's not the cleanest, but it does the job.

```
 ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
          var value = viewValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
          value = $filter('number')(value, 0)
          value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')

            return value
        });
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXRLad)

Comment: Good, number filter came to rescue... :)

Comment: Beware, the number filter will add ',' character. So ought get something like 2,345 instead of 2345. Hope it's not a problem for you.

Comment: Yeah that's why I had to use the regex to remove non-numeric characters.